# How to use onBackPressed() directly in my xml android:onClick

Tags: android

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_back"
        android:title="Back"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:onClick="onBackPressed"
        />

</menu>
```

I want to access the override function

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(CaseInfoActivity.this,DashBoardActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

directly when the back button is pressed and i also set the line in my xml to

```
 android:onClick="onBackPressed"
```

but it still wont work!
Firstly is this possible?
If yes!, then how?

Comment: No, it's not possible, directly. The target method must have a `MenuItem` parameter.

Comment: Make another method that method inherits from activity and it can not be called from xml. Also it does not even have a View as one parameter.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve that using android databinding.

create layout file with variable of your activity:

```
<variable name="activity" type="Activity">
```

in `onClick` call `onBackPressed()` method:

```
android:onClick='@{() -> activity.onBackPressed()}'
```

and add in your activity

```
getBinding().setActivity(this);
```

Look at [databinding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#variables) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.back) {
        onBackPressed();// it will call the onBackPressed() method
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or Try this to get click event of Action bar back arrow

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Logd("Home pressed","");
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

Comment: what if i want to use it with ImageButton in my CUSTOM TOOLBAR?

Answer (score 0):

```
       <variable
                name="loginpageevent"
                type=".............model.LogInPageClick"/>

    add this ->android:onClick="@{(view)->loginpageevent.backbuttoncalled()}"

    <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/back_button"
                    android:onClick="@{(view)->loginpageevent.backbuttoncalled()}"
                     />

then in activity class 

 LogInPageClick  logInPageClick=new LogInPageClick(this);

then in Model class, how to call onbackpressed or finish();

public class LogInPageClick {
    private Context context;


   public LogInPageClick(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }
 public void backbuttoncalled() {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        activity.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```